# Parse Json value to html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, jquery-mobile

How can i parse each tag of k and v to html tag.

```
var json = $.parseJSON(data);
var x = 0;
$(json).each(function(i, val) {
    $.each(val, function(k, v) {

        var my_href = "#";
        var img_source = "..img";
        var my_title = "...abcd";
        var slider_index = "wows_" + x;

        x++; //increment link id

        $('#ws_images').html('<li><a href="' + my_href + '"><img src="' + img_source + '" alt="" title="' + my_title + '" id="' + slider_index + '" /></a></li>');

    });
});
```

The json is as follows:

```
[  
   {  
      "news_id":"8",
      "title":"ddd",
      "description":"ddd",
      "photo":"News_images\/20020_1116863714996046_8844424307040103167_n.jpg",
      "posted_on":"2015-07-12 12:54:48",
      "news_type":"image_slider",
      "dept_id":"1"
   }
]
```

The value of k return the tag name but how can each tag element be parsed into the html tag.

```
<li><a href="' + my_href + '"><img src="' + img_source + '" alt="" title="' + my_title + '" id="' + slider_index + '" /></a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing single `$.each()` , substituting `.append()` for `html()`

```js
var data = [{
  "news_id": "8",
  "title": "ddd",
  "description": "ddd",
  "photo": "News_images\/20020_1116863714996046_8844424307040103167_n.jpg",
  "posted_on": "2015-07-12 12:54:48",
  "news_type": "image_slider",
  "dept_id": "1"
}];

  $.each(data, function(k, v) {

    $("#ws_images")
    .append("<li><a href=#>"
            + "<img src=" + v. photo 
            + " alt=''" 
            + " title=" + v.title
            + " id=wows_" + k + " />"
            + "</a></li>");

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<ul id="ws_images"></ul>
```